# after fs crash and running fsck, some files were recovered but not place in lost+found?

Tags: linux, data-recovery, fsck, e2fsck

I had a I/O error on an external hard drive partition sdb4 (its usual mountpoint being /run/media/yan/data).

The partition was non responsive, couldn't be accessed and refused to unmount. I did not know what to do but unplug the disk and replug it. After that I had error on its fs, so I ran fsck:

```
sudo e2fsck /dev/sdb4 -y -v
```

It was asking for a lot of fixes (thousands) but since data is non-critical on that disk, I ran it with -y.

```
data contains a file system with errors, check forced.

Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
# Fixed invalid inode numbers, incorrect filetypes, cleared links, deleted/unused inodes
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
# Connected unconnected directory inodes to /lost+found
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
#Fix inodes ref count, connected unattached inode to /lost+found
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
# Fix block bitmap differences, blocks count wrong for group
# Fix inode bitmap differences, directories count wrong for group, free inodes count wrong for group

data: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****

       72955 inodes used (0.14%, out of 51200000)
        2390 non-contiguous files (3.3%)
          17 non-contiguous directories (0.0%)
             # of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 0/0/0
             Extent depth histogram: 72264/636/1
   186984621 blocks used (91.30%, out of 204800000)
           0 bad blocks
          34 large files

       70447 regular files
        2453 directories
           0 character device files
           0 block device files
           0 fifos
  4294966642 links
          46 symbolic links (46 fast symbolic links)
           0 sockets
------------
   71063 files
```

So if I understand correctly, fsck managed to salvage 70k files, so most of the files since I had like 75-80k files on that disk. The problem is that only 20k files appear in '/run/media/yan/data/lost+found', and only 24k on the entire partition.

```
[yan@machine ~]$ find /run/media/yan/data/lost+found | wc -l
19786
[yan@machine ~]$ find /run/media/yan/data | wc -l
23691
```

I reran fsck but he tells me that the partition is clear (and has 74k files ?)

```
[yan@machine ~]$ sudo fsck /dev/sdb4
fsck from util-linux 2.28
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
data: clean, 74200/51200000 files, 186685980/204800000 blocks[/cpp]
```

I also have very different disk usage according to df and du (I know there should be a difference, but here it seems too big to be normal):

```
[yan@machine ~]$ df -h /run/media/yan/data
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb4       769G  700G   31G  96% /run/media/yan/data

[yan@machine ~]$ du -sh /run/media/yan/data
586G    /run/media/yan/data
```

I'm guessing there is still recovered data that I can't access.
My questions are :

1) Is it possible for recovered files by fsck to not be place in lost+found ? In that case, where are they ?

2) Is there any way to get back those missing files ?

3) If not, how do I free this space ?

EDIT:

I tried a more recent version of e2fsck on sourcejedi's recommandation:

```
[yan@machine build]$ sudo ./e2fsck/e2fsck -f /dev/sdb4
e2fsck 1.43.3 (04-Sep-2016)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Inode 40501578 extent tree (at level 2) could be narrower.  Fix<y>? yes

Pass 1E: Optimizing extent trees
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

data: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
data: 74200/51200000 files (3.2% non-contiguous), 186685964/204800000 blocks
```

It did not do much, lost+found still has the same file count and size.

Answer (score 0):

i also notice link count is very suspicious (nearly 2^32).

you can try more recent e2fsck, and/or report a bug.  this is certainly a bug.

scanning the device/partition with `photorec` might restore more files, where the format is supported and they are contiguous.  since your FS is quite full, many files are not contiguous.  `photorec` does not recover file names or directories.  (e.g. if they're mp3's, you can use something like `picard` to apply filenames from the mp3 metadata aka ID3 tags).  note `photorec` requires free space on another filesystem, to recover all the files to.

Comment: e2fsck was 1.42.13, the latest version disponible in repos. I've build the latest version 1.43.3 and tried it too (see my edit), but to no avail. Apparently, I have few non-contiguous files (which is in fact not really surprising, I almost never erased files on that fs, I'll try photorec once I received my new HDD). I might also try to open a ticket on whatever code repository e2fsck is using. Still, thanks for your answer.